# Moving an ImageView center point at the correct time

Tags: ios, ios6, uiview, uiimageview

I have a center point for an UIImageView which is being updated.

At present the issue is that I see the image view move. What I am looking for is to move the imageview when the view is hidden and then show it again once the center point is updated.

I created a method that does the center point update:

```
-(void)updateCenterPoint {
    float newhintX = (self.originalImageCenterPoint.x * self.scaleDownOriginalImageRatio) + self.insideImageFrame.frame.origin.x;
    float newhintY = (self.originalImageCenterPoint.y * self.scaleDownOriginalImageRatio) + self.insideImageFrame.frame.origin.y;
    if (self.hintView.hidden == NO) {
        self.hintView.hidden = YES;
        self.hintView.center = CGPointMake(newhintX, newhintY);
    } else {
        self.hintView.center = CGPointMake(newhintX, newhintY);
    }

    if (self.hintView.hidden) {
        self.hintView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Calling this in viewDidLoad does not appear to work how I expect it to. Ideally when the view loads I do not want to the see the hintView (image view) until it is in the correct point?

Comment: Do you see animation of moving or it just blinks to new position? Hiding and unhiding immediately it will not help at all. It is no different than just setting the center.

Comment: Yes, it just blinks to new position

Comment: If you see it on old position, that means you are not calling this method at the correct time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was updating the center point from a method:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

This is called at some point which is too early. So the center point is still 0,0 even though it is being updated.

This meant that the view was becoming unhidden/shown before the center point had changed, therefore when the method was called again the update occurred to the centerpoint.

The resolution was to check that the point was not 0,0 if it was keep it hidden. It is never going to be 0,0 in my example - luckily.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this:

```
 Hide the image
 Move the image
 Unhide the image
```

Instead of asking if it is hidden etc. explicitly hide it, move it, then unhide it.

Jeff

Comment: When the view is initialized is it hidden or visible? If you don’t want to see it until it is in its correct position I would think it should be initialized and set to hidden. Move it to its proper position and then unhide the view.

Comment: That is what I tried, the problem is rotation too. I then need to hide it and recalculate the correct center and show it again in the correct place, can't seem to work it out